# Etymology of the words "narky" and "narked"

Tags: etymology, british-english

Anybody have any idea where the word **"narky"** comes from?

I speak British English and I understand the word to mean *irritated* or *bad-tempered*. Similarly I've heard the phrase **"narked off".**

> ### Examples
>
> *He got really narky with me when I pointed out that he'd made a mistake again.*
>
> or
>
> *I got really narked off when my little sister lost my favourite necklace.*

Comment: narc or nark+ -y where nark means someone who is annoying or disturbing.

Comment: The strange thing is that _nark_ in that meaning is mentioned as Australian slang, where _narky_ is British slang. (_Nark_ in British slang is a police informer).

Comment: Any relation to "snarky" in American English? Seems to mean the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Narky* and *narked* both come from the verb [*nark*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/nark?q=nark) (not from *narc*, which is unrelated).

*Nark* means "to cause annoyance" and is derived from the Romany for *nose* (*nāk*).

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/narc shows narc and nark are synonyms

Comment: @PoojaRaja yes, but that *nark* is not the same word as the *nark* I refer to here. See [narc](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/narc?q=narc).

Comment: The link I provided clearly says that nark is a variant of narc and it also means a lawman concerned with narcotics violations.

Comment: Yes, the first meaning in your link is a variant of *narc*, but that is unrelated to the meaning that means an annoying person.

Comment: The Romany nak (nose) giving rise to a copper's nark (police informer) seems very plausible. But how did we get from nose to annoying? I suppose there's analogy with something 'getting up my nose'.

Comment: Maybe something related to nosy people being quite annoying.

Answer (score 1):

I think it might have some relation with French [**narquois**](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=9fbpc7iyL2UC&pg=PA427&lpg=PA427&dq=narquois+narky+narked&source=bl&ots=N-pyrZyyuZ&sig=3bXx9iaYYT3_TfRhELsUacoLmy8&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=ZShyU4PzEu-b1AX_2ICwBQ&ved=0CDgQ6AEwBDgK#v=onepage&q=narquois%20narky%20narked&f=false).

> [**narquois**](http://www.littre.org/definition/narquois): mocking; [**derisive**](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-anglais/narquois/53454).